# Increment sleep/wait time until required

Tags: java, multithreading, events, wait, synchronized

I'm not very good in multi-threading, this might be a basic question. But i have'nt been able to find an answer.

**Scenario:**
Lets say I have an event listener which is fired by something. Every time the event is fired, i want to start a new thread which takes about 3 seconds to execute.

**Problem:**
The problem is that the event can be fired more than once in a second, and I don't want to start multiple threads at once.

**Requirement:**
How can I schedule a thread lets say at 1000ms after the event. If the event keeps on firing, i want to keep delaying the scheduled time of thread. This way my thread executes after 1000ms of the last time the event was fired.

Comment: Why are you performing the action in a separate thread ? why not in the actionPerformed method itself?

Comment: @VishalK The OP might not want to block the EDT every time the event if fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `ScheduledExecutorService` - schedule the task to happen in one second and if there is a task already scheduled cancel it and schedule a new one to happen in one second

This way your task will execute one second after the last time the event was triggered.

```
private class Task implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private Future<?> scheduledTaskHandle;

private class Listener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (scheduledTaskHandle != null && !scheduledTaskHandle.isDone()) {
            scheduledTaskHandle.cancel(false);
        }
        scheduledTaskHandle = executorService.schedule(new Task(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

The `Task` is a `Runnable` that does your long-running operation. the `Listener` is your listener class.

In the `Listener.actionPerformed` method we first check whether a task is already scheduled by using the `Future`, if it is we cancel it. We don't need to worry about race hazards here is if the tasks finishes in between the call to `isDone` and the call to `cancel` then nothing will happen.

If the task is running at the point when the `Listener` fires then that task will complete, as the `cancel` method is called with `false`. Another task will be scheduled to run one second after the firing of the listener or once the currently running task has completed (as we are only using a single thread no more than one task can run).

The `Listener` will then schedule a new execution of the task to happen in one second.

Answer (score 3):

The event listener, on start up, creates and starts a new private thread. The thread contain a list of tasks to do and executes them one at a time sequentially. Each time the even listener receives a new event, it creates a new task, and adds it to the list of tasks in the private thread.

EDIT: Eugene suggested using a Thread Pool, which might be beneficial in your case if you have a great amount of work to do with each task taking up considerable amount of time. Take a look at thread pools in Java API, like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: what if there are 1000 tasks? I think that a Thread Pool would be much better

Comment: @Eugene, that is a fair change. I thought OP was timing task execution (3 seconds) including the creation of the thread, which probably takes up 90% of the time, so I did not think a pool was necessary, but I'll add it in.